# Переключение между формами без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, form

Есть две формы одна для регистрации другая для логина, изначально нам выводится форма регистрации. Внизу под ними есть переключатель типа если мы хотим залогинется то жмем его и нам выводится формочка для заполнения данных для входа, если нам захотелось снова в регистрацию то мы нажмали на кнопку и у нас снова форма регистрации это все нужно сделать без перезагрузки страницы.

Изначально да и сейчас смотрю в сторону аякса вот сам скрипт
    '

```
<script>
$(function(){
        $('#form').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testik.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#result').html(result)
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

'
а вот обработчик
    '

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['test'])) {?>

<style type="text/css">
#form {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<form id="formq">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="button" name="te">
 </form>

<?}?>
```

'
то есть я просто хочу подменить одну форму другой но переключатся я не могу. Понимаю что у меня гавнокод, но я не так давно этим занимаюсь и много не понимаю еще, может кто-то что подскажет.

Answer (score -1):

Сделай два контейнера с формами, в первом поставь `display: none` и при переключении просто поменяй у другого на `display: none`, а у первого на `display: block`